# Parse RRULE to readable text?

Tags: calendar, icalendar, rfc2445, rfc5545, rrule

I am looking for a library (php) or some pseudocode to parse Ical RRULEs to readable text(like for example google calendar)

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1FR,3FR,5FR

-> Monthly on Friday of weeks 1, 3, 5 of the month
```

Comment: Though not aware of any library, are you aware of all the quirks the RRULE allow (BYSETPOS, BYHOUR, ...) which can make translation in human language difficult: FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1 is "last work day of the month", but BYSETPOS can be a list which can make the reading quite random. To the point: a subset of RRULE could be made human readable but 100% conversion is likely a true challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing and I struggled to find one, but I found one which is still in development, and you can find it here: https://github.com/simshaun/recurr/tree/v0.2-dev

I was able to get it working with this code:

```
$timezone        = 'America/New_York';
$startDate       = new \DateTime('2013-06-12 20:00:00', new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
$rule            = new \Recurr\Rule('FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=5', $startDate, $timezone);
$textTransformer = new  \Recurr\Transformer\TextTransformer();
echo $textTransformer->transform($rule);
```

I believe it's not perfect yet and I guess it's still changing while in dev, but looks very promising.