# iCalendar RFC 5545 to string

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

Is there any opensource library for displaying human readable description for recurring events described by the above standard?

I want to obtain `every 5 weeks on Thursday` for rule `RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=5;BYDAY=TH`

Language C# is preferred but not required at all

Comment: this request is similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646111/parse-rrule-to-readable-text and has a similar answer: the complexity of rrule makes it a non-trivial problem to solve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript you might use [rrule.js](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) library, It's very useful for generating human readable texts from RRULE string.

You can try it out from [this link](http://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/).

BTW, as far as I know **ical4j** and **google-rfc-2445** didn't have any functionality for generating human readable texts.

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

1. [DDay.iCal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/) - .NET 2.0
2. [ical4j](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html) - Java
3. [google-rfc-2445](https://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/) - Java
4. [iCalcreator](http://kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/) - PHP
5. [php iCalendar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpicalendar/) - PHP
6. [libical but it seems broken](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2006/04/msg00167.html) - C
7. [pyICSParser - disclaimer: I'm the maintainer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyICSParser) - python

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a list of good libraries. Sorry for my english: I definitely need to change my question, because I mean not just parsing but "human readable description of event in input .ics file"